# PHP SimpleXMLElement not making quotes into entities

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, xml-entities

I'm writing a PHP script to generate some xml docs and I am having some issues with SimpleXML and quotes.

If I have code like this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<myxml />');
$xml->addChild('title','My Feed');
$xml->addChild('description','Entity data here - &amp; &quot; &apos;');
```

If I print_r the $xml obj then I get this:

```
print_r($xml);
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
  [title] => My Feed
  [description] => Entity data here - & " '
)
```

Which seems that once in the object it makes the entities back into their respective characters.  However when I call asXML() on the object to get the XML it shows me this:

```
echo $xml->asXML();
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <myxml>
  <title>My Feed</title>
  <description>Entity data here - &amp; " '</description>
</myxml>
```

It make the & back into an entity, but it seems to leave the quotes as characters.  Shouldn't it convert them all to entities?

Answer (score 5):

`"` and `'` are only special characters in XML if they are inside an attribute value. Within the text content of an element, there is no ambiguity as to the meaning of `"` or `'`, as the next special token being looked for is `<` to start an opening or closing tag.

So while `<foo bar="hello "world"" />` is invalid XML, `<foo>hello "world"</foo>` is not, so no escaping is *required*.

(Just because it's not *required*, doesn't mean it's not *possible*, so there may be a fuller answer as to why SimpleXML doesn't at least retain the entities you'd put there voluntarily.)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the problem is a bit deeper:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49437

It's a "feature" or a bug in underlying **libxml** library: by default all entities (except ***lt* *gt*** and ***&***) are being unescaped.

The irony here is that you can explicitly enable unescaping (LIBXML_NOENT), but you cannot disable it.

I found the only way to deal with it: use **CData** nodes where data left untouched as it is. But that's not an ideal solution of course.